# Setting values of a column of Multiindex based on its index

Tags: pandas, indexing, multi-index

This my Multiindex dataframe:

```
                        A   B   C   D   E   F     G   H    I    J
Chars  Date
       2020 January   4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 February  4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 March     4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 April     4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
Chars2 2020 January   4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 February  4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 March     4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 April     4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
```

For example, I want to make a change on March and after March but only 'B' column. How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
df.xs('Chars2')[df['B'].index.get_level_values(1).month >= 3] = 20.40
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'month'
```

And then, I tried something like this. But I could not achieve my desired output.

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['B', pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(1), errors = 'coerce').month >= 3] = 20.40
```

My expected output:

```
                        A   B   C   D   E   F     G   H    I    J
Chars  Date
       2020 January   4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 February  4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 March     4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 April     4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
Chars2 2020 January   4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 February  4.0  66  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 March     4.0 20.4 45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 April     4.0 20.4 45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
```

Comment: Can you add expected output DataFrame?

Comment: I added expected output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 masks, chain them by `&` for bitwise AND and then set values of `B`:

```
m1 = pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(1), errors = 'coerce').month >= 3
m2 = df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'Chars2'

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'B'] = 20.54
print (df)
                        A      B   C   D   E   F     G   H    I    J
Ch     Date                                                         
Chars  2020 January   4.0  66.00  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 February  4.0  66.00  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 March     4.0  66.00  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 April     4.0  66.00  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
Chars2 2020 January   4.0  66.00  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 February  4.0  66.00  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 March     4.0  20.54  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
       2020 April     4.0  20.54  45  26  99  20  13.5  15  3.8  3.2
```